# minimum number of bits in a microinstruction to specify two kinds of microoperations?

Tags: cpu-architecture

This is an examination question, it would be very kind if you could explain it to me,

My question is:

A micro instruction is to be designed to specify:

a) none or one of the three micro operations of one kind, and

b) none or upto six micro operations of another kind

The minimum number of bits in the micro instruction is:

1) 9

2) 8

3) 5

4) none of these

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not asked very clearly and had I received it on a test I would have asked for clarification, but this is how I read it;

- The first condition (None or any one out of 3 operations) gives 4 variations to consider. This uses 2 bits.
- The second condition (Any combination of 6 other operations) gives 64 variations to consider. This uses 6 bits.

In total 8 bits.

Answer (score 0):

A] none or one of the three : vertical micro programming = log (n+1)= log (3+1)
                                                        =2 bits

B] none or upto 6: horizontal micro programming   = n bits 
                                                  =  6 bits

minimum no. of bits 6+2= 8 bits

Answer (score -1):

Really?
I would say 4 because it depends on the processors instruction set and width of other input and address busses.

Comment: But no other information is given and the answer is given to be the second option i.e. 8